# Methods for tracking option open interest intraday

Tags: options, derivatives, quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, trading-systems

It is my understanding that open interest option values on financial websites are a reflection of a snapshot value each day. Is anyone aware of methods for estimating intraday open interest, or aware of any financial data vendors that offer their estimations on this?